# Firestore collection's document amount

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting to use firestore database as my database and I have wondered if there is any limit to the amount of documents I have in a collection.

Thansk

Comment: None [listed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore scales massively.  That means there is no theoretical limit to the number of documents you may have in a collection.  Queries will always scale to the number of documents in your result set, not the number of documents in the collection.

If you manage to find a limit - congratuations!  You've found a use case that the team hasn't anticipated.  Also, you're probably paying a lot of money to store and access all that data!